# SVN Checkout Errors on "Format 6"

Tags: svn, svn-server

When I try to checkout a repository with SVN I get the error:

> E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'

I've read that this has to do with mismatched versions, however both my SVN server and client are running version 1.8.1.

(Edit:)
I've been following this tutorial: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/updating-svn-mac-os-x/
I started with a prebuilt MacPorts version of SVN, then I built my own to see if it would fix the issue.

I am serving with SVNServe. I am testing the server on the server, so the client and the server are the same instance.

Here are the exact versions (I believe they are one package):

```
svn --version
svn, version 1.8.1 (r1503906)

svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.8.1 (r1503906)

svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.8.1 (r1503906)
```

If I create a repo with `--compatible-version 1.7`, but that just seems silly since everything is version 1.8+.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you hosting Subversion (apache, svnserve, etc.)?  Did you build your own, or are you using what was packaged by the OS?

Comment: Answered on stack overflow [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259360/subversion-svn-e160043-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-4

Comment: This normally shows up when client and server versions are incompatible. So explain at least which versions you have installed (client and server), and how you have setup the repository you want to use.

Comment: Details and questions answered in the body of the question. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Have you created the repository on the server anew? Or is that repository a copy from somewhere? Have you tried to create a new repository (with `svnadmin`), and then checkout that repository locally (which should work)? There is no information in your question where the repository did come from.

Comment: The repo was created with this instance of SVN admin.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be relevant but I will throw it out here in case it helps.
I was having similar problem using the checkout feature ('Open from Version Control...') with Delphi Xe5 & now Xe6.
Here's how I fixed it in both.

**Step 1:**

- Update the **32bit** version of SVN
  Download the latest version is (or that matches your stuff) at the time of the posting of this reply it's "Subversion 1.8.8 (Windows 32-bit)"
  from http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion
  Note: Even if you are using TortoiseSVN 64 bit you still have to install/update the 32 bit version because Delphi's IDE is still only 32 bit.

**For Delphi Xe5**

- Copy updated files from:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client
  to
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\12.0\bin\subversion

**For Delphi Xe6**

- Copy updated files from:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client
  to
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\14.0\bin\subversion

**Note:**

- the Delphi folders listed above are the default folders (*at least how they installed on my system*) so your paths may be different.
- 2 of the SVN files (MSVCP100.DLL and MSVCR100.DLL) the C++ runtimes were newer in my Delphi folders, so probably don't want to overwrite them.
- and of course don't have Delphi running when you are updating the files.