# Issue in importing project from SVN repository

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

SVN repository is created using Tortoise SVN in D: drive of the machine.

While trying to import project from svn repository, following error is displayed on console.

*

```
Couldn't open a repository
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///D:/repository/trunk'
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///D:/repository/trunk'
Unsupported FS format
svn: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'
```

*

Please suggest the possible causes and fixes for this issue. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259360/subversion-svn-e160043-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-4

Answer (score 1):

> svn: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'

means, in plain English "You have outdated SVN-client, which can't operate on repository of newest version of SVN"

Repository was created in 1.8-format, client can operate only with <=1.6 repositories