# Using Windows Notepad as commit log message editor in Subversion

Tags: windows, svn, notepad

I am trying to set up subversion on windows. I followed this blog (http://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/) and did the setup as instructed, it was successfully installed i think, but i am stuck somewhere in-between while testing if it is working or not

After doing this :

```
set SVN_EDITOR=c:windowssystem32notepad.exe
svn mkdir svn://localhost/myproject
```

it opens up notepad and i modified and saved it and it was suppose to ask for credentials and all but it is showing some other messages.
[image]

I am not sure how to make it working.  Am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This was down to a version conflict. I have Tortoise version 1.8 installed on my PC and I was downloading version 1.6 of Subversion.

**Solution:**

[Subversion: SVN E160043. Expected FS format between '1' and '4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259360/subversion-svn-e160043-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-4)

`svnadmin create --compatible-version 1.6 PATHNAME`

Fixed my problem.

Comment: The format of a repository is completely unrelated to the original question about notepad.exe. BTW, don't use SVN 1.6 or 1.7. Both these versions are not supported anymore. Use 1.9 or 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you didn't save the commit message in notepad.exe. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and close Notepad. You should see authentication prompt after this step. If the server allows anonymous access then the commit should start without any additional actions.

Comment: ... or whatever short-cut you see in your localised version of the File-> Save menu ;)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to save your message correctly. If you have to work with Windows/OSX parallely, be aware that you have to use different Shortcuts(Windows: <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> OSX: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>). Otherwise it should work, if the server allow access (as you're hopefully the admin)

Comment: @bahrep May be windows security issue or something, Whenever i save using ctrl+s it says "Log message unchanged or not specified" as shown in the screenshot.