# Subversion 1.9.2: Invalid filesystem format option 'addressing logical'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, redhat, svnserve, fsfs

I installed SVN 1.9.2 in UAT Linux redhat 6.6 using tarball and run the SVNSERVE as daemon and all went fine. Then I created a repository and configured the repo for client access and tried to access the repository using tortoiseSVN but could not access the repository. Seeing the error,

"db/format contains invalid filesystem format option addressing logical"

Before installing in UAT, I tried in TEST server but I could install and access the repository with no issues. I am using Redhat 6.6 Server. Anyone seen this issue. I am stuck since next week we have production installation.

---

**Edit:** Actually I moved to SVN installed bin directory and started the svnserve as daemon. The svnserve started was the one which is shipped with Redhat OS. It solved the issue when invoked the svnserve with full path.

Comment: Which version of TortoiseSVN are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.7.10. I figured out the issue. I moved to installed directory and started as svnserve -d -r root-path. This command invokes the default  svn shipped with Redhat server.

Comment: Sure, good to hear it's working again :) Nevertheless I did some research, as I have a feeling this question might come up more often.

Comment: While you run svnserve, you access the repository over file:// schema. Aren't you?

Comment: When exactly do you get this error and what URL do you use to access the repository?

Comment: @ Baharep - Just noticed that i missed to respond. I used svn://servername/repositoryname. The path to svn binary was wrong so it through the error. Now it solved.

Answer (score 4):

Although the OP solved his problem - by going back to an old version of Subversion (probably 1.6.x as he says it's the default shipped with RHEL6.6) - the error symptom poses a valid question which deserves more research.

Subversion 1.9 introduced a new version of their [FSFS file system (v7)](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure), which is the filesystem used in the repository (not the working copy). If the repository in question was created by a 1.9 server, it seems it *may* cause [compatibility problems](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/30942047/fisheye-unable-to-recognize-the-svn-repository---unable-to-make-progress.) with older clients when accessing through `file://` protocol. The error message `invalid filesystem format option 'addressing logical'` corresponds to the new FSFS v7 feature "Logical Adressing".

About client-server, the [compatibility matrix](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#new-feature-compatibility-table) clearly states there is no issue, as far as the server code version supports the FSFS file system version of accessed repositories.

**Note:** Since 1.9, you can use the `svnadmin info` subcommand to check a repository's features (on the server). It even gives a hint which level of client compatibility the repository bears. Unfortunately, I don't have a 1.9 repo at hand for testing, but here's some example output:

```
Path: /repos/apache
UUID: ac336b0e-000b-11e0-b354-23d019ddd9ed
Repository Format: 5
Compatible With Version: 1.8.0
Repository Capability: mergeinfo
Filesystem Type: fsfs
Filesystem Format: 6
FSFS Sharded: yes
FSFS Shard Size: 1000
FSFS Shards Packed: 1631/1631
FSFS Logical Addressing: no
Configuration File: /repos/apache/db/fsfs.conf
```

Comment: "compatibility" problem you refer to may occur when using Subversion 1.8 older client to access the repository locally over `file:///` access schema. This is NOT client-server incompatibility. OP gets the error because he attempts accessing the repository over `file:///` when the client acts as server and client both. Should he access the repository over http(s) or svnserve the error won't occur. Another possible reason: the server is not Subversion 1.9, but some older version.

Comment: @bahrep: Thanks for the input. If that's true I'll withdraw my scribbling. Still, some notes: SVN server is explicitly 1.9 on RHEL6.6 as per OP's question. SVN client is TortoiseSVN 1.7, which is a Windows client, so access via `file:///` is quite unlikely.

Comment: let's wait OP clarifying this :)

Comment: The SVN server installed in latest 1.9.2 in Redhat6.6 and accessing svn repos using svnserve. below is svnadmin info.
Path: /<path>/Repo
UUID: a079313c-77dd-11e5-94ae-b1684fb5e5f3
Repository Format: 5
Compatible With Version: 1.9.0
Repository Capability: mergeinfo
Filesystem Type: fsfs
Filesystem Format: 7
FSFS Sharded: yes
FSFS Shard Size: 1000
FSFS Shards Packed: 0/0
FSFS Logical Addressing: yes
Configuration File: <path>/Repo/db/fsfs.conf
I believe when repos accessed using svnserve, there is no client-server compatibility.

Comment: @bahrep: Does the added information help to clear this up?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue when migrating a few repos from RHEL 6.4 / subversion 1.6.11 to RHEL 7.4 / subversion 1.9.7.

I found the answer from this question worked for me:
[Subversion: SVN E160043. Expected FS format between '1' and '4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259360/subversion-svn-e160043-expected-fs-format-between-1-and-4)

> If you want to create backwards-compatible repositories from v1.8, you can use the `--compatible-version` flag. example:
>
> ```
> svnadmin create --compatible-version 1.6 PATHNAME
> ```
>
> http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure has a list showing which FS formats are compatible with different versions of svn. But you should just check the versions of svn on the machines that you are going to use, and make your repo compatible with the oldest version.