# Eclipse Oxygen will not connect with the SVN server

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I have  ‘TortoiseSVN 1.10.0, Build 28176 - 64 Bit , 2018/04/14 08:00:32’ and it works in non Eclipse situations.  I have read and followed most of the reverent post on Stackoverflow and others.  Still no joy.   I have added the SVN plugins, except for ‘JavaHl’ which failed after an hour of trying.  My Eclipse is:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200
The current situation is:
When I try to add the Repository Location, I get:
[image: Error message]

I have also tried ‘file:///P:/SMC/TortoiseSVN/Projects/’  fails with the same message.
This is what TortoiseSVN gives me in a checkout dialog. When I look at the ‘Repository Browser’ I see:
 [image: Repository Browser]

I tried several other variations and none of them worked.

When I look under window→preferences→team→ SVN, I see:
[image]

I also do see an entry in the pull down for ‘Native JavaHL 1.8.11” but it gives the almost same error.
Thanks in advance Cliff2310

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a filesystem (FS) repository (URL starts with `file://`), so no SVN server is involved and Eclipse or the connector of Subversive accesses the files directly.

The [**filesystem format 8** is understood by **Subversion 1.10**, not by 1.9](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure). Unfortunately, there are no SVN 1.10 connectors for the SVN Eclipse plug-in Subversive yet. Also [Subclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse) which is an alternative to the [Subversive](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subversive-svn-team-provider) Eclipse plug-in does not yet but [will support SVN 1.10 in the next upcoming release](https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

As a **hack** you can change the version in the **file `db/format` from 8 to 7**. But beware, this could also destroy the repository.

The better solution is to **downgrade the repository**. A non filesystem repository would perform better. On Windows you can use e. g. [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) for that and the latest version (3.9.0) should be able to import your FS 8 repository since it [supports SVN 1.10](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/).

Comment: I think you have the answer, but I'm new to SVN, so I'll hope for a simpler answer.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to replace `8` by `7` in the file `db/format`. But make a backup of the directory that contains the repository if it doesn't work first. To create new repositories use Eclipse or `svnadmin` with the option [`--compatible-version 1.9`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18862823/6505250).

Comment: Well I changed the 8 to a 7 and now I get: Location information has been sepcified incorrectly. svn: E160004: Malformed text rep offset line in node-rev.    i used the same location as above.

Comment: Too bad. You could try the current Subclipse snapshot build (update site: `https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/snapshots/`). It looks like it contains a JavaHL SVN 1.10 connector. Uninstall Subversive before, both SVN plug-ins don't work well together.

Comment: In SVN connector I see both the SVNkit and JavaHL, I'm not shure how the JavaHl got there.  Should I remove one? If so which one?

Comment: JavaHL wraps a DLL as Java API and SVNKit is 100% Java. To read an FS 8 repository an SVN 1.10 connector is required (JavaHL or SVNKit). Subclipse has an SVN 1.10 connector which is not yet released but already available in the current snapshot build. You have the Subversive plug-in, not the Subclipse plug-in. Both plug-ins are very similar.

Comment: I tried the current Subclipse snapshot build. Eclipse chewed on it for more that a hour and then gave up. So I guess no SVN for eclipse.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well just for the heck of it I went and tried to connect with the SVN server and it worked! I do not know if it will all be OK, but I connedcted with the server.

Comment: Well it connects to the setver, but dosent talk to it, so still no joy.

Comment: If the repository URL starts with `file://` there is no server, the SVN client accesses the file system directly.